# Application not working on Windows XP

Tags: .net, windows-xp

I created a .NET 2.0 application on Windows 7.

When I tried to run the .exe on my Windows XP machine [SP3 as well as SP2], it doesn't start up. It shows me a message that Windows has encountered a problem....send error report...

Any known issues?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You will need to provide more detail than this, such as the error details.

Comment: This is a very very broad question, you'll want to be more specific to get a good answer here. The "encountered a problem" error could be... well... anything.

Comment: I checked the event viewer and got this description;
 
EventType clr20r3, P1 powerpointviewer.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4c0c82d3, P4 powerpointviewer, P5 1.0.0.0, P6 4c0c82d3, P7 3, P8 32, P9 system.security.security, P10 NIL.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: It also says; Event Id 5000 and Source: .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting. However, I had deployed 2 more applications along with it [same target tun time], they worked with no problem. So I dont think that I dont have proper runtime installed in the machine. moreover this being SP3 would have .NET 2.0 for sure

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. The event log entry mentions "system.security.security" - are you trying to run the application from a network share?

Comment: ah! @Jeremy, you solved that! :) 
While this got resolved I am getting an error for one more app;   

EventType clr20r3, P1 scribble app final.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4bd70a14, P4 presentationframework, P5 3.0.0.0, P6 45398c20, P7 6496, P8 be, P9 system.windows.markup.xamlparse, P10 NIL.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

NOw what does this mean :(

Comment: I'm also running into an exact same problem with "system.windows.markup.xamlparse", have you solved that?

Comment: Try catching the unhandled exception. Also, check if you have proper .net runtime installed.

Comment: I post a similar problem to yours, and have not been solved. See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802176/net-application-cannot-start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Copied from a comment:)

The event log entry mentions "system.security.security" - are you trying to run the application from a network share? If so you'll need to relax permissions (unless you're using .NET 4.0) as by default the security model doesn't permit applications to run from there.

You may also find it useful to use the Remote Debugging capability of Visual Studio to attach the debugger to a remotely running application.