# .NET application cannot start and receive XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I wrote an app that can install and work on my development PC (a Window 7).

- Development Environment: Window 7, VS2010 WPF C# with both **.NET 4** and **.NET 3.5** installed

On other client computer (XP SP3, 2 and 1), it install with no error, but can not start. In task manager, I can see the application takes up memory briefly before closing by itself.

I had made sure .NET 3.5 consistency across my develop PC and various client XP machines by following:

- The application targets **.NET 3.5** (or **3.5 Client Profile**)
- Use VS2010 Installer for deployment: targets **.NET 3.5** in Launch Condition
- No error whatsoever about .NET compatibility during debug of application and installer project

**eventvwr** caught the following warning:

```
 ¬º˛¿‡–Õ:   ¥ÌŒÛ
 ¬º˛¿¥‘¥:   .NET Runtime
 ¬º˛÷÷¿‡:   Œﬁ
 ¬º˛ ID:    1026
»’∆⁄:       2011-10-18
 ¬º˛:       15:18:32
”√ªß:       N/A
º∆À„ª˙: WWW-9DB69D5A3AF
√Ë ˆ:
Application: Foo.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: ”…”⁄Œ¥æ≠¥¶¿Ìµƒ“Ï≥££¨Ω¯≥Ã÷’÷π°£
“Ï≥£–≈œ¢: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
∂—’ª:
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   ‘⁄ MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   ‘⁄ System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   ‘⁄ System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   ‘⁄ System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   ‘⁄ System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   ‘⁄ System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   ‘⁄ MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   ‘⁄ MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   ‘⁄ MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   ‘⁄ MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   ‘⁄ MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   ‘⁄ System.Windows.Application.Run()
   ‘⁄ FooSoftware.App.Main()


”–πÿ∏¸∂‡–≈œ¢£¨«Î≤Œ‘ƒ‘⁄ http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp µƒ∞Ô÷˙∫Õ÷ß≥÷÷––ƒ°£
```

there was this XamlParseException causing my app to not start on XP Window Machine. What is going on?

Comment: Did you check eventvwr on those machines?

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory yea..not any informative.

Comment: I've edited my question with an exception I found in eventvwr, but no solution yet.

Comment: Try building it explicitly for x86 instead of 'Any CPU'. I'd expect a "bad image format" if this makes any difference but you never know.

Comment: Have you tried different XP machines? Or just on one?

Comment: I have this issue on one client machine out of thousands. It's driving me batty!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`XamlParseException` is the generic error that happens when there is a problem at application start. I suggest you modify you application startup code to trace what's really going on and get, not only the XamlParseException, but also the inner exception(s) which should help you determine the root of the problem. Here is an example:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            // hook on error before app really starts
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }

        void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            // put your tracing or logging code here (I put a message box as an example)
            MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting a StackOverflowException, removing the call to **base.OnStartup(e)** seemed to fix it.

Comment: Where is the InnerException here? We are simply getting ExceptionObject which is just an object. How can I trace InnerException?

Comment: @teenup - e.ExceptionObject is usually of Exception type

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, I managed to catch a bunch of exceptions in other areas of my code with this. However, it does not catch the XAMLParseException that is thrown. Even with this before `base.OnStartup()`

Comment: @douglasg14b - you should ask another specific question if you have a more specific problem

Answer (score 7):

For starters, you'd actually have better luck if you built on VS2010 .. but actually *targeted* for a *lower* version of .Net (3.5, or even 2.0).

It would definitely be helpful if you post a bit of code.

Make sure you've copied all the necessary files for your application (app.config, etc).

This link sounds similar:

[.NET 4 Program written/compiled on Windows 7 machine won't run on XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054863/net-4-program-written-compiled-on-windows-7-machine-wont-run-on-xp)

And it points to these excellent troubleshooting tips:

[Using Fusion Log Viewer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)

Comment: thanks. I am using VS2010 and as you suggested, targeted 3.5 or 3, but multiple references that cannot be resolved by a lower version of .NET. In this case, does it mean all application written to target .NET 4 cannot be used in XP SP2 or lower?

Comment: No, you don't *need* to target Net 4.0 unless your app explicitly uses .Net 4.0 features.  In general, you can usually write more "portable" code that targets lower versions of .Net.  And yes, the .Net runtime *requires* XP SP3 or higher: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17113

Comment: Back port it to 3.5. Same problem persist. I started to think it could be a bug in VS2010.

Answer (score 6):

You can remote debug. Basically this is done by installing the remote debug server on the target machine, then attach to it from your visual studio when you start the application. Some more info can be found here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx
and there's a somewhat elderly tutorial here : http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/visual_studio_remote_debugging.html

Please note that you must deploy with debug symbols (pdbs) and the software debugged must be in the same version that your code is in.

Answer (score 6):

Although you were targetting .NET 3.5 your client hat .NET 4 installed and used it. The string

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
```

does tell me this. 
To force your client to actually use .NET 3.5 you should add an [App.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) to your application and add:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

It could be that you are getting an exception because .NET 4 treats your XAML in a different way. Did you try to let your application run under .NET 4? If you have no App.config supplied you did test your application with .NET Framework 4 anyway although you did target .NET Framework 3.5.
If your client is nice enough you can let him create a dump file so you have an easy way to debug it directly.
Download [Procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) from the SysInternals tool suite and send it along with your application to your client. The let him execute

```
procdump -ma -e -t -x foo.exe %temp%\dump.dmp
```

This will generate a full process dump for every unhandled exception and another one when the process terminates into the %TEMP% directory. Visual Studio 2010 has gotten much better dump analysis support so you should be able to analyze it within Visual Studio 2010.
If that does not help you can download Windbg (32 bit [here](http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/debuggers/dbg_x86_6.11.1.404.msi)), load the dump and type

!analyze -v

to see what the last exception was. That should do the trick. There may be issues with the managed extensions to load the [right debugging dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373683/unable-to-load-sos-in-windbg) (sos.dll for .NET 2,3,3.5, and clr.dll for .NET 4) but there are plenty of tutorials online how to do it. Besides this I would recommend to add exception handlers into your application so you get a nice log file when your application does terminate in an unexpected way.

If the output did not lead to the right stack you shold use
!ClrStack
and 
!Threads
to find out which threads have exceptions on their stack.

Answer (score 5):

Usually what I do is put log files in between processes so I know the flow of my program.

If this is a console application, put Console.WriteLine(some string) and then you can put Console.ReadLine() at the end to pause the execution of your program.

Answer (score 4):

Came across a similar problem recently. The problem I had is on windows 7, I was using .ico (icon files). But there is no support for these on XP. In your application, if you are using any icon files, try removing them.. see if this solves the issuse.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However, after I delete and remove all the icons on my app, the same problem stil persist - it doesn't not start and no error or crashes being picked up.

Comment: Do you have a XP system(like a virtual sys) with Visual studio installed? If so, try debugging it there. Since you are running .exe on the XP machine, it is hard to see exceptions. But with debugging on VS, you will see the exact problem. Icon issue was found like that

Answer (score 3):

Start commenting out lines of code and entire classes/methods from your code until you get it working (Or start by commenting out everything). Then slowly start introducing lines of code and method calls etc. Until it breaks. This should give you an idea of any particular code/class or reference that is causing the problem. This is admittedly a tedious method, but at the same time, fairly mechanical and within an hour or so you should have a fairly good idea of culprit.

Answer (score 3):

I heard that some commented codes affected on execute output file to behavior something like that happened for your app.(specially in VS 2010 not other earlier version)
but in other side,last year i was working on a program that in it i used the Dev Component suite. as you know its crack just work in .Net Framework 3.5 and my program platform was .Net Framework 4.same thing happen for your app, happened fro my app.i had to downgrade my platform to 3.5 and its work good.maybe this personal experience help you dude.

i want to say some thing else,this some errors are not depend on CPU architecture.Dot worry about it.

good luck. Ali Foroughi

Answer (score 3):

The "TryCathcWhen"-related line makes me think about some unhandled exception on startup, **or** an exception is being thrown in a catch block on startup.

Seeing your startup code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen on machines where the installation of .NET 3.5/4 had failed/not successfully completed. However, this is also highly unlikely.

You should try to install remote debugging on the machine (fairly easy process) and then setting the remote machine as the target in Visual Studio, run the program in debug mode. The program will then launch on the remote machine and you will get the full error within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had a .Net 2.0 app that worked with debugging on But not in a release build(after install).
I wasn't getting any logging from my Application directly, my Errors came straight from .NET. The issue was I had created my Own Program class with a static void MAIN() inside the main I had a `try...catch..finally` block.  For some reason .NET was choking on the `finally`.  Do you have anything like that in your program?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a generic error. In my case freshly installed application failed to create its own event source due to insufficient permissions. Resolved (ugly one) by running the app one time in "as admin" mode. Make sure that all inner exceptions are handled. Events is also a good source of information.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem solved when the user installed the same .Net FW version that I was developing for. (I has FW 4.5.1 and user had FW 4.0).

So, check the FW version:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

And install exactly the same before trying again to execute

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I had a similar exception:

```
Application: Foo.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.get_Current()
   at Prism.Regions.RegionManager.CreateRegion(System.Windows.DependencyObject)
   at Prism.Regions.RegionManager.OnSetRegionNameCallback(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfMemberInvoker.SetValue(System.Object, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(System.Xaml.XamlMember, System.Object, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlMember, System.Object)

Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Foo.App.Main()
```

The key part in my case above was the `CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.get_Current()`.  My application did not use `ServiceLocator` anywhere; however, it appears that it was being used by a NuGet package I had installed.

I solved the problem by performing this in the NuGet Package Manage console for my main app project:

```
PM> Install-Package CommonServiceLocator -Version 2.0.5
```