# WPF application cannot start when user is standard user on win7

Tags: .net, wpf

When the user is an administrator, the application runs well. But when the user is a standard user the application crashes on startup .
[image]

I got the exception information use code from
[.NET application cannot start and receive XamlParseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802176/net-application-cannot-start-and-receive-xamlparseexception)

I am using VS2010 and .Net 4.0.

Event Log:

```
Exception Info: 
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException Stack: 
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri) 
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri) 
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean) 
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri) 
at MyApp.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() 
at MyApp.MainWindow..ctor() 
at MyApp.App.Main(System.String[])
```

update:

I create a default WPF application without any change.
it still crash.

Comment: the application run well on win xp

Comment: Are you loading in a file that is in your program directory?

Comment: Yes, it show a splash window (inherited from class Window, not class SplashScreen) when the application start, the splash image (png format) is stored in the application.

Comment: this link (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919180%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) talk about this problem, but it cannot solve it

Comment: it run well on the computer without vs2010

Answer (score 2):

The application is trying to load a file that the user has no access to.

Probably an image, video or sound file.

Try to pin-point the xaml/file that is causing the issue by commenting-out fragments of the Xaml until you find the file.

After that grant access to the file by either chaning the security on the file or by placing the file somewhere more public.

Comment: it run well on the computer without vs2010

Comment: Do you mean without running the debugger or running on a machine that has no Visual Studio?

Comment: I mean vs2010 is not installed on the computer.

Comment: you could try to use fuslogvw http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx to findout what assemblies are loaded on a machine with and on a machine without VS. That is the only thing I can think of how an installation of VS might influence the running of an app

Comment: fuslogvw required administrator privileges, but this problem is only for standard users.

Comment: You could run the app as the user and run fuslogvw as admin