# C# WPF.MDI without dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, mdi

I found source of [WPF.MDI](https://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/) and I try to use it in my project without any specific dlls. So, I added source into the project

[image]

Then, wrote xmlns declaration `xmlns:mdi="clr-namespace:WPF.MDI"` and created a container with `MdiChild`

```
    <mdi:MdiContainer Theme="Aero">
        <mdi:MdiChild />
    </mdi:MdiContainer>
```

But, I received an error `XamlParseException`.

I guess, I do it wrong at all. But, there is any solutions for this?

UPDATE:
When I put WPF.MDI.dll into folder with .exe file and start it - there is no errors. Why it wants to find dll?

Comment: Did you also receive some kind of detailed error message about what went wrong?

Comment: `Call the constructor for type"WPF.MDI.MdiContainer", satisfying the specified binding constraints, led to an exception." Row number "7" and the position in the "10."` the string is `<mdi:MdiContainer Theme="Aero">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after deleting the strings 96-100 in `MdiContainer.cs`

```
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5)
            ThemeValueChanged(this, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(ThemeProperty, Theme, ThemeType.Luna));
        else
            ThemeValueChanged(this, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(ThemeProperty, Theme, ThemeType.Aero));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your namespace declaration like this:

```
 xmlns:mdi="clr-namespace:WPF.MDI;assembly=MDISource"
```

So add the `assembly` part.
You need to add this if your class is in a different assembly. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> assembly= The assembly that contains some or all of the referenced CLR
>   namespace. This value is typically just the name of the assembly, not
>   the path, and does not include the extension (such as .dll or .exe).
>   The path to that assembly must be established as a project reference
>   in the project file that contains the XAML you are trying to map. In
>   order to incorporate versioning and strong-name signing, the assembly
>   value can be a string as defined by AssemblyName, rather than the
>   simple string name.
>
> assembly can be omitted if the clr-namespace referenced is being defined within the same assembly as the application code that is referencing the custom classes. Or, an equivalent syntax for this case is to specify assembly=, with no string token following the equals sign.

**UPDATE**
[Read this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7857728/2478357)

Comment: It's not helped for me. What I need to write instead `MDISource`? i don't get it

Comment: You can ignore this answer, I read your question wrong. You added the MDI in the same project, right? Then this isn't needed.

Comment: Yes, I add it in the same project

Comment: I tried it, but message doesn't show:( Maybe, because exception comes earlier.